# org-clock-display breaks links

Tags: org-mode

When i press <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-d</kbd> (org-clock-display) emacs expands links in headers. How to prevent this?

Sample file:

```
* h1 
** [[http://duckduckgo.com/?q%3Dvery%20long%20search%20term%20blabla][DuckDuckGo]]
   CLOCK: [2015-07-03 Pt 11:18]--[2015-07-03 Pt 11:30] =>  0:12
```

**before:**

[image]

**after running org-clock-display:**

[image]

Links is expanded and i don't see the time near second headline.

Comment: The same thing happens in [clock tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html), and you can specify a `:formatter` property -- perhaps there's a workaround by generating a clock table and using a formatter that strips out the links?